# Excel Range.Value returning 0 when range actually has data

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, windows-server-2008

**Environment**: Windows Server 2008 (SP1) 64-bit | Excel 2007.

I have a value in a range (say 60.664). When I run the line of code in the immediate window I got a `Null` as a result `a blank space`:

```
?Workbooks("ddWorkbook.xlsm").Worksheets("Daily Dashboard").Range("D23").Value
```

Using a `Select` and `ActiveCell` statement, like below, works however.

```
Workbooks("ddWorkbook.xlsm").Worksheets("Daily Dashboard").Range("D23").Select
ActiveCell.Value
```

I can leave this quick and dirty with the `Select | ActiveCell`, but I would like to leave this done with best practice.

Has anyone ever come across this and how to get the `Value` to read right from the Range Object? I have not found anything in my research.

Comment: Does it work if you save `Workbooks("ddWorkbook.xlsm").Worksheets("Daily Dashboard").Range("D23")` in a Range object variable first? If not, do the same with the second variant `ActiveCell`. When you have both range variables set, try to test for identity with the `Is` operator and find out what the differences are. If saving to a Range variable works then this should be the preferred workaround to messing with `ActiveCell`.

Comment: where you been man?  Missed the other side to Scott^2.

Comment: @ScottCraner - very busy these days, my brother. Thanks for the note :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could be that the cell `D23` is in a merged area but not the first cell of this area. This would explain why you are getting the value after a `Select`.
You can check it by printing the address once the range is selected:

```
Workbooks("ddWorkbook.xlsm").Worksheets("Daily Dashboard").Range("D23").Select
Debug.Print ActiveCell.Address
```

And if it's the case, then you can either fix the range or try to get the value from the merged area:

```
Workbooks("ddWorkbook.xlsm").Worksheets("Daily Dashboard").Range("D23").MergeArea.Cells(1,1).Value
```

Comment: Thank you! Had I seen that it was a merged cell from the beginning I wouldn't have asked the question, but this lead me to look further! Turns out columns C and D are merged, but C is hidden. I assumed that because it was hidden it would not be merged!